# Does react have mechanism to move children in different dom level,like function of GlobalKey in flutter

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem that move children in different dom levels will lose children state. Is there any solution like `GlobalKey` in flutter?

Demo

```
function ({children,someFlag}:{children:ReactNode,someFlag:boolean}){
  return someFlag?<div><div>{children}</div></div>:<div>{children}</div>;
}
```

Comment: you can learn about react portals https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Comment: Seem that protals can not solve my problem.I add a demo to clearly demonstrate my problem.

Comment: https://github.com/httptoolkit/react-reverse-portal can slove my problem